# What is the percentage of Republican voters who would/wouldn't vote for a female President?

Tags: united-states, public-opinion, presidential-election

Are there any polls which estimate **what percentage of Republican voters would/wouldn't** vote for a female Presidential candidate in a general election if said candidate was in line with their political views (meaning, they would vote for a male candidate with identical views/qualifications)?

I'm fine with any reasonable definition of "Republican" voters as long as the definition used is clearly spelled out in the poll methodology.

I'm NOT interested in polls estimating specific candidates as those depend highly on specifics of who's running.

Comment: *Which* female?  Do they have other accomplishments besides being a woman?

Comment: The trouble with this question is it is purely about identity politics.  I wouldn't vote for the "first female President" just as such because it's *incorrect relative importance.*  So the question is ridiculous.  "Would you trust a doctor who wore sandals instead of shoes?"  Answer: Why are you worrying about your doctor's shoes instead of his/her *medical competence?*

Comment: @Wildcard  It seems pretty clear that this is a question about whether or not being female would be a disqualifying factor or not to republicans, not whether or not they will vote for any candidate who happens to be female.

Comment: Wildcard you are looking at this backwards.  It is not that being a female qualifies someone, but that certain demographics will *disqualify* a candidate purely for being female.

Answer (score 5):

[June 15 CBS News poll](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/clinton-maintains-lead-after-claiming-nomination-cbs-news-poll/) states that 70% of Republicans surveyed believe these United States are ready for a Woman president.

Question: Do you think America is ready to elect a woman president, or not?

### Methodology:

> This poll was conducted by telephone June 9-13, 2016 among a random sample of 1,280 adults nationwide, including 1,048 registered voters. Data collection was conducted on behalf of CBS News by SSRS of Media, PA. Phone numbers were dialed from samples of both standard land-line and cell phones.
>
> The poll employed a random digit dial methodology. For the landline sample, a respondent was randomly selected from all adults in the household. For the cell sample, interviews were conducted with the person who answered the phone.
>
> Interviews were conducted in English and Spanish using live interviewers.
>
> The data have been weighted to reflect U.S. Census figures on demographic variables.
>
> The error due to sampling for results based on the entire sample could be plus or minus three percentage points. The margin of error for the sample of registered voters is four points. The error for subgroups may be higher and is available by request. The margin of error includes the effects of standard weighting procedures which enlarge sampling error slightly.
>
> *This poll release conforms to the Standards of Disclosure of the National Council on Public Polls.*

```
Results:
                         Tot R  D  I  May Poll  
    Yes                  79  70 86 79 78  
    No                   18  28 10 18 20  
    Don't know/No answer  3   1  3  4  2
```

Comment: Could you please expand a bit (poll methodology, exact question wording)

Comment: Looking at your link I suspect the question was a bit different (not "who you'd personally vote for" but "is US as a country ready"). The two sets don't necessarily match - someone may easily dislike the idea of a female President but honestly acknowledge that the country as a whole is ready for that; and vice versa, someone may support the idea but assume that the rest of the county isn't ready.

Comment: I expect this will be as close as you can get to a relevant and truthful answer. The "would you vote for a female presidential candidate?" questions gets very close to "Are you sexist?" and will skew the results because people will not answer truthfully.

Comment: The same poll also asked the question "Do you personally hope that the United States has a woman president in your lifetime, or not?" The answers to this question may be closer to what the OP was looking for. (R/I/D percentages answering "yes" are 52/74/85.) http://pollingreport.com/politics.htm

Comment: @dcsohl Not knowing the demographic spread of those polled, I can't interpret their life span.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what these numbers look like in 2015 or 2014 as well.  I'd hazard a guess poll conducted in the week after Hilary Clinton became the presumptive Democratic nominee, is going to skew results simply because the question "ready now a female president" could easily be conflated with "ready for Hilary Clinton as president" for a portion of either party's voters.

Comment: @DrunkCynic A fair point; I was just thinking anybody who "hopes" there will be a woman President in their lifetime would be somebody who'd be willing to vote for a woman, given the right woman at least. In other words, a lower bound to the OP's question.